# Selecting data from keyword columns in SQL CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am trying to query my SQL CE to retrieve database meta data - at the moment I am trying to fetch the index data using:

`select * from information_schema.indexes`

However this query is going to be run programatically - and needs to return the needed columns in the right order. Therefore, I have built the following select statement:

`select Table_Name, Table_Schema, Index_Name, Clustered, Unique,
Column_Name from information_schema.indexes`

However, the words `Clustered` and `Unique` are reserved keywords and they cannot be used in a select statement. Doing so, I get the following error: `There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number: 1,Token line offset: 45, 0,Token in error: Clustered,,]`

I found a similar issue here ([Using SQL keyword in title of table or column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921770/using-sql-keyword-in-title-of-table-or-column)) but the solution does not seem to work with SQL CE (wrapping column name in back-ticks).

Any ideas how I can actually select data from keyword columns in SQL CE?

Comment: You could also use my scriting API, then you do not have to write any SQL statements- http://exportsqlce.coeplex.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That post is about doing this in MySQL.  SQL Server (of which SQL CE is a derivative) uses square brackets as field identifiers, so surround the field(s) in square brackets [].

```
select
    Table_Name,
    Table_Schema,
    Index_Name,
    [Clustered],
    [Unique],
    Column_Name
from information_schema.indexes
```

Answer (score 1):

Surround with square brackets:

```
select [Table_Name], [Table_Schema], [Index_Name], [Clustered], [Unique], [Column_Name] from [information_schema].[indexes]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as accepted but I upvoted yours too :)